# 'one to many' attribute value type should not be 'persistence entity'

Tags: hibernate

I have 1 user to many another domain and put this in my code:

User class

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_USUARIO",unique = true,nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "usuario.cadastro.nome.obrigatorio")
    @Column(name = "NOME", unique = true, nullable = false,length = 100)
    private String nome;

    @Email(message = "usuario.cadastro.email.invalido")
    @Column(name = "E_MAIL", unique = true, nullable = false,length = 100)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "usuario.cadastro.senha.obrigatoria")
    @Column(name = "SENHA", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String senha;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<DiasUsuarioTimeSheet> diasUsuarioTimeSheetList;


    public Usuario() {
        diasUsuarioTimeSheetList = new LinkedHashSet<DiasUsuarioTimeSheet>();
    }
```

Another class:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DIAS_USUARIO_TIMESHEET")
public class DiasUsuarioTimeSheet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_DIAS_USUARIO_TIMESHEET",unique = true,nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DIAS_ID_DIAS", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Dias dia;

    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Column(name = "USUARIO_ID_USUARIO", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Usuario usuario;

    @Column(name = "TIME_SHEET_ID_TIME_SHEET", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private TimeSheet timeSheet;

    public DiasUsuarioTimeSheet() {
    }
```

I have error in:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
private Set<DiasUsuarioTimeSheet> diasUsuarioTimeSheetList;
```

'one to many' attribute value type should not be 'persistence entity'

Answer (score 7):

The following annotation

```
@Column(name = "USUARIO_ID_USUARIO", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

should be

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USUARIO_ID_USUARIO", nullable = false)
```

the `unique=true` attribute doesn't make sense, since it's a ManyToOne association: you'll obviously have several DiasUsuarioTimeSheets referencing the same user.

Similarly, the following annotation

```
@Column(name = "TIME_SHEET_ID_TIME_SHEET", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

must be replaced by

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TIME_SHEET_ID_TIME_SHEET", nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<mapping class="com.company.models.DiasUsuarioTimeSheet"/>
```