# 'Many To One' attribute type should not be 'Persistence Entity'

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm trying out IntelliJ IDEA and it's warning me of a Hibernate association that I don't quite understand.

One Side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_REQ_ASSIGNEE")
public class MyRequestAssignee extends BaseUser {
    //...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "myRequestAssignee")
    private Collection<MyRequest> myRequests = new ArrayList<>();
    //...
}
```

Many Side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_REQUEST")
public class MyRequest implements Persistable {

   //...
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="ASSIGNEE_ID")
   private MyRequestAssignee myRequestAssignee;
   //...
}
```

(`Persistable` is just an interface that has the `id` property to make sure Hibernate has access to it.)

I see the `MyRequestAssignee` type underlined in red and the message reads `'Many To One' attribute type should not be 'Persistence Entity'.`  Are there something wrong with my relationships?

For a sanity check, I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500776/one-to-many-attribute-value-type-should-not-be-persistence-entity) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby) too.

Comment: I have a similar problem with my `@ManyToMany` relationship. The code works, though

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I found this to be caused by the child entity not being defined in hibernate.cfg.xml.  The error message could be improved.

Comment: Adding `<mapping class="com.company.domain.MyRequestAssignee"/>` to the hibernate.cfg.xml resolved this.

Comment: Awesome.  I should have been more explicit about what to add to hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: If you are using JPA, it might be an entry in the persistence.xml that's missing.

Comment: @TheChrisPratt Correct.  Or it could be in your `annotatedClasses` property of your `LocalSessionFactoryBean` bean config for Spring.

Comment: Using JPA, it means that the entity MyRequestAssignee has to be added in persistence.xml

Comment: If you are using annotations instead of XML, you need to add a @ManyToOne annotation to your field. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927091/save-child-objects-automatically-using-jpa-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this issue in my **multi-module Gradle** project with **Quarkus** in **IntelliJ**,
where I have a OneToOne reference from an entity of module A to an entity of module B.

[image]

**The code works, so I guess it could be a false flag of IntelliJ**

Comment: Did you check if your AuthUser had the @Entity annotation?

Comment: @V.Dimitrov yes, the issue was explicitly related to the multi-Module structure

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error appears because I omitted to declare @Entity en the other side class

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but I just wanted to add that this can also be caused by a conflicting hibernate .hbm mapping file and JPA annotations. I ran into this error message when converting old mapping files to annotations and forgot to comment out one of the old mapping files.

Comment: Another reason for this error can be if you forget to add the `@Entity` attribute to your target class. I ended up here when searching for this (even though that wasn't OP's problem)

Comment: @MetalMichael you are a saviour